# When using numberfield, the 0 value will be removed at the begin of the sequence

Tags: sencha-touch-2, phone-number

I have a numberfield like below

```
               {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    name: 'phoneNumber',
                    label: 'Phonenumber',
                    required: false
                }
```

When a user inserts a value like 3832, it will be saved right but when the user sets a value with 0 at the begin of a sequence like 0123, the zero will be removed and only 123 will be saved.

In my case I want to store some phonenumbers which have a 0 value at the begin.

PS. the phoneNumber in the model is a string, so it will be saved as a string

```
{ name: 'phoneNumber', type: 'string' }
```

How could I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use a TextField seen as you phone number is being saved as a string?

Comment: Because then I have to make a validation to check if the value the user added is valid (a number instead of letters).

In first case I made it with a textfield but I couldn't get the validation work properly.
This was my validation:
{ type: 'format', field: 'username', matcher: /[0-9]{0,20}/}

The field should not be required and only number should be allowed. The value should not be bigger than 20 characters.

Comment: A numberfield is for entering numbers, isn't it? But leading zeros have no significance for numbers, unless they're meant to specify the base, like in many programming languages where a number literal starting with a 0 means it should be an octal number. So the leading zeros are discarded when parsing the number [or set the base for parsing, no idea about sencha] and what you get is the **number** and it's impossible to reconstruct the number of preceding zeros. Telephone numbers **are not numbers**, they are strings, and you ought to treat them such, use a TextField.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
How should my validation look like when I'm using a textfield instead of a numberfield? This one doesn't work:
{ type: 'format', field: 'telefoonNummer', matcher: /[0-9]{0,20}/}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should using a `textfield` and in controller to checking `Ext.isNumeric(phoneNumberValue)`

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on your problem. Use your model like this. Also use **textfield** instead of a **numberfield**.

```
             {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'phoneNumber',
                label: 'Phonenumber',
                required: false
            }
```

**mymodel.js**

```
        Ext.define("Stackoverflow.model.mymodel", {
            extend: "Ext.data.Model",
            config: {

                fields: [
                    { name: 'phoneNumber', type: 'string' },

                ],
                validations: [

                    { type: 'presence', field: 'phoneNumber', message: 'Enter a Phone number.' },
                    { type: 'format', field: 'phoneNumber', matcher: /[0-9]{1,20}/}

                ]
            }
        });
```

And then validate this inside your controller. I hope you have code for model validation.( If not leave a comment)

Comment: Thanks for you response! In your mymodel.js, the phoneNumber field is required but in my case it shouln't be required. It is an optional field so I think the presence type should I remove but how should the matcher look like to achieve this?

Comment: @StackFlower yes u can remove type: 'presence' from model ,if it is optional. are u getting any errors in implementing above code ?

Comment: When I have the following validation, the field is required because of the {1,20}            { type: 'format', field: 'phoneNumber', matcher: /[0-9]{1,20}/}

If I change this 1 to an 0 like this:
            { type: 'format', field: 'phoneNumber', matcher: /[0-9]{0,20}/}  then the validation doesn't work anymore. It now also accepts letters instead of only 0-9 values